# Cannot edit: <link rel="canonical" - OS Commerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, canonical-link

I am using Filezilla to edit my site.

Q: I need to edit the `<head>` section of a product page on OSCommerce. Is this possible on a product by product basis?  I want to edit the canonicals.

The code looks like so:

```
    <base href="url0>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="url2">
<link rel="canonical" href="url3" />
```

However the site is built in OS Commerce and it seems like this might not be possible.

Every page on my site references a canonical, to its own page. This has likely been done by a script though as I don't seem to be able to edit a file which contains the canonical tags.

AFAIK each product page does not have its own page of html you can edit on OScom, unlike WP or MG2O.

Has anybody got any experience with OScommerce that could shed some light on this problem?